# loop is increasing each time through select/inserts

Tags: php, odbc

I have a script that is pretty straight forward in theory, where I"m trying to select relational data on a development DB2 database, and insert into a separate production db2 server (creating new IDs and relationships on the production side in the process).

So in this script, I:

- Select from the dev ITEM table
- Store the original primary key
- insert the data into the dev ITEM table
- Get the ID of the newly inserted one
- select SUBITEM from dev with the original ID
- for each subitem I insert the data into the prod SUBITEM table with the newly created ITEM ID as the relationship

The problem is the script actually runs successfully, but as it goes, it simply increases by one so even though it inserts each ITEM correctly, it ends up just getting EVERY subitem in the database and storing the original (1st row's) ID. FOr instance:

My first ITEM select returns ID 1204. By the time I let it run for several items, my ITEM table shows records with IDs: 1204,1205,1206 and 1207

That's correct, but when I look at the subITEMS table, I have 10 subITEM records all with itemID of 1204. So it got the right subitem for each iteration of ITEMS but only ever inserted the very first newID variable.

What did I do wrong here:

```
if($DB2connDEV && $DB2connPROD){

    $getDevItems = "
                SELECT 
                    itemt_ID,
                    DESCRIPTION
                FROM itemt 
            ";

    $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connDEV, $getDevItems);

    while($gettingDevItems = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){
        $rows[] = $gettingDevItems;
    }

    foreach($rows as $row){
        $prepInsert = odbc_prepare($DB2connPROD, "INSERT INTO itemt (itemt_id, description) VALUES(?,?)");

        $originalID = $row['itemt_ID'];
        $description = $row['DESCRIPTION'];

        $insertTable = odbc_execute($prepInsert, array($description));

        //Get newly created ID       
        $getIdentity = "SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS LASTID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1";

        $stmt = odbc_exec($DB2connPROD, $getIdentity);
        $row = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);
        $newID = $row['LASTID'];

        if($newID) {
            echo "Last Insert ID is : " . $newID . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "No Last insert ID.\n";
        }

        //Get subItems and insert 
        $getSubItems = "SELECT NAME, DESCRIPTION
                FROM SUBITEMT
                WHERE itemt_ID = $originalID";

        $selectSubItems = odbc_exec($DB2connDEV, $getSubItems);

        while($gettingSubItems = odbc_fetch_array($selectSubItems)){
            $subItemRows[] = $gettingSubItems;
        }

        foreach($subItemRows as $subItemRow){
            $subItemPrepInsert = odbc_prepare($DB2connPROD, "INSERT INTO subitemt (itemt_id, NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES(?,?,?)");
            $subItemName = $subItemRow['NAME'];
            $subItemDescription = $subItemRow['DESCRIPTION'];

            $subtaskInsertExec = odbc_execute($subtaskPrepInsert, array($newID, $subItemName, $subItemDescription));

            //get newly created ID for subitem
            $getsubtaskID = "SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS LASTID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1";

            $subtaskIDSTMT = odbc_exec($DB2connPROD, $getsubtaskID);

            $newsubItemRow = odbc_fetch_array($subtaskIDSTMT);
            $newSubItemID = $newsubItemRow['LASTID'];

            if($newSubItemID) {
                echo "Last Insert subItem ID is : " . $newSubItemID . "\n";
            } else {
                echo "No Last insert subItem ID.\n";
            }
        }
    }

    odbc_close($DB2connPROD);
    odbc_close($DB2connDEV);
}
```

Comment: `$prepInsert` has two placeholders, but you only have one value in `array($description)`. It should be `array($itemt_ID, $description)`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry that was actually a typo that I didn't notice, my code does have that though. I think I accidentally removed it in formatting for this post

Comment: Figured, since the code won't even run without it.

Comment: Why are you doing the first `INSERT INTO itemt`? You're inserting the same thing you just selected.

Comment: @barmar I'm selecting from a database on a separate IP/Server for development, then inserting on a production IP/Server with a different connection

Comment: This is our way of replicating it because we have conflicting Primary Keys already on production so we can't just dump all of the data

Comment: If you want to generate new, unique IDs on production, you shouldn't be specifying the `itemt_id` column in the `INSERT`.

Comment: I guess that's a bit confusing from my post: I am creating new IDs in the new insert table, but I"m inserting the 'old' IDs into a separate column as a legacy identifier. SO I"m inserting the old ID to keep track while we migrate, but I'm also creating the new ID upon insert (which is working). I just can't figure out why it's not inserting the subITEMS only with their relative ITEMs

Comment: Consider keeping prepared calls outside loops. Nothing changes so no need to call each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not clearing out `$subItemRows` between iterations of the main loop. So each time you're adding the new subitems to the subitems from the previous iterations.

Put

```
$subItemRows = array();
```

before the loop:

```
while($gettingSubItems = odbc_fetch_array($selectSubItems)){
    $subItemRows[] = $gettingSubItems;
}
```

Comment: ah YES!!! That's it, I'm not sure how I overlooked this to begin with! I really appreciate your help on this

Comment: I ran into this before, I should remember to always set the empty array that way before looping

Comment: There's no reason to create the array in the first place. You could just do everything inside `while $subItemRow = odbc_fetch_array($selectSubItems))`

Comment: That makes sense. So there's no reason for me to clear out the $rows[] array at the top level either?

Comment: `$rows` is only used once so it doesn't matter.