# Insert data array on php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is code I wrote:

```
foreach ($quotefile as $quote_files) {
    $clone_quote = str_replace('PP', 'PR', $quote_files);
    $file = 'uploads/quotation/' . $quote_files;
    $newfile = 'uploads/pr/' . $clone_quote;
    copy($file, $newfile);
    $files[] = array(
        'PONO' =>  $pr_no,
        'PP_ID' =>  $pp_id,
        'FILENAME' => $clone_quote,
    );
    $this->M_pr->send_pr($files);
}
```

And this `send_pr()` function:

```
function send_pr($files)
{
    $data = $this->db->insert_batch('PR_FILE',$files);
    return $data;
}
```

This is the output that goes to the database:

[image]

why are some data rows repeating like that? I want the data to insert into the database, not duplicates.

Comment: try dropping ` $this->M_pr->send_pr($files);
` out of loop

Comment: Related: [loop is increasing each time through select/inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60289080/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling insert function inside loop, so it's getting repeated, move it outside

```
foreach ($quotefile as $quote_files) {
  // your  initial code
}
$this->M_pr->send_pr($files);// put this line outside of loop
```